# DropdownCheckList does not show all selected variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this plugin for jQuery: http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/ but it does not show the default multiple selected variables

This is my code:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
<option value="13">Item 13</option>
<option value="14" selected="selected">Item 14</option>
<option value="15" selected="selected">Item 15</option>
<option value="16">Item 16</option>
<option value="17" selected="selected">Item 17</option>
</select>
```

But, it only shows item 14 (first selected) as selected, while there are 2 more..

Additional info: It does work as expected in IE7, IE8, Firefox4

Does not work in Chrome 12.0.742.100, but does work as expected with Chrome 14.0.797.0 dev-m

Since it does work in the dev channel, I'm supposing Google will put a fixed stable version of chrome online soon™ so never mind the question :)

Comment: it is working fine to me in Firefox 3.6, which browser you are using dear?

Comment: Chrome 12.0.742.100 at work! :)

Comment: try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gUCPF/9/) and let me know.

Comment: @Asad I fail to see the difference between your and my code, but it seems its a bug in the current stable version of chrome..

Comment: that is your code I paste in jsfiddle that is it Ok in browser, and I found it working in mozilla and chorme but I am using chorme 10.x.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Chrome 12.0.742.100